# How to remove strings from a list that contain more than 7 unique characters?

Tags: python

What is the correct way to remove strings that contain more than 8 unique characters from a list?

Let's say for example, that I have a list that looks like ['jazz', 'messu', 'jazzmessu', 'jazzmessut'] and I need to remove 'jazzmessut' from the list, because it contains more than 7 unique letters (j, a, z, m, e, s, u, t).

I have been trying to remove such words from a file like this:

```
file1 = ['jazz', 'messu', 'jazzmessu', 'jazzmessut']
file2 = []

alphabet = [x for x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']

for word in file1:
    if set(alphabet) in set(word) < 8:
        file2.append(word)

print(file2)
```

Yet this only returns an empty file, so I must be doing something wrong.

Should I somehow split each word before comparing them as sets or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over once and check if the length of the unique letters is less than 8 instead.

```
>>> file1 = ['jazz', 'messu', 'jazzmessu', 'jazzmessut']
>>> file2 = [file for file in file1 if len(set(file)) < 8]
>>> file2
['jazz', 'messu', 'jazzmessu']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it like this:

```
file1 = ['jazz', 'messu', 'jazzmessu', 'jazzmessut']
file2 = []

for word in file1:
    if len(set(word)) < 8:
        file2.append(word)

print(file2)
```

You don't need an alphabet list, and your condition is wrong: set(alphabet) will almost never be contained in set(word) (the word must contain all the different letters of the alphabet in order to do so!), so the condition if set(alphabet) in set(word) is wrong. Furthermore, even if it was True, the next condition would be <8: you're basically doing True < 8, which would be always False because True is represented as 1 as integer.

The condition you need to write is instead:

```
if len(set(word)) < 8
```

By doing it like this, you are checking if the word contains more than 8 distinct letters

Comment: Thanks for the help and for explaining, where I went wrong! Much appreciated!

Comment: Because of [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), `a in b < c` is equivalent to `(a in b) and (b < c)`, except that `b` is only evaluated once.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that!